# why my expo app's fonts don't work on android but on web it works fine

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, fonts, expo

that is my app in github:
https://github.com/Ammar0203/expo

why my expo-react-native app's fonts don't work on android but on web it works fine

it says :
(fontFamily "DMRegular" is not a system font
and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported
  by your device operating system.
- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with
  Font.loadAsync.)

it says that for all of the fonts i have searched all the web for a solution non of them worked
i'm coding that from a youtube tutorial (Build and Deploy a React Native App | 2023 React Native Course Tutorial for Beginners)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ3bGvy0WAY&t=418s
i have reached to ( 40:58 ) in the video

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

const Layout = () => {
  
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    DMBold: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf'),
    DMMedium: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf'),
    DMRegular: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf'),
  })
  
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if(fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded])

  if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return null
  }

  return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView} />
}
export default Layout
```

I have tried adding 'react-native.config.js' and i tried the old way `Fonts.loadAsync()` also i did not add fontWeight property in my stylesheet and also i tried deleting my node_modules folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed it my terminal showed me that i need to fix the versions of my modules it said:
"Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:
expo-font@11.6.0 - expected version: ~11.4.0
react-native@0.72.3 - expected version: 0.72.5
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
Fix with: npx expo install --fix"

so all i had to do is run in the terminal "npx expo install --fix"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your file added incorrectly. It is `react-native.config.js` at the root of your project and you are showing `react-native-config.js.`.

Documentation showing as such [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

Comment: sorry it was a mistake in typing the question. it is written "react-native.config.js" but still not working, i have edited my question and added a github link for my app so if you want to check what is the error